# select query returns different results for the same query

Tags: mysql, innodb

i have a table in my db called `events` here is some info about the table

```
106,528 ROWS  -     InnoDB  -   utf8mb4_unicode_ci -    35.1 MiB
```

in this table i store sport match events

today i've noticed something weird , when i run a select query i get something different time to time

this is the query , basically looking for the matches without the result

```
select * from `events` where `stat_forms` > '0' and ((`result_added` = '0' and `archived` = '0' and `start_time` < '1530901263') or `result_error_flag` != '0') and `events`.`deleted_at` is null limit 20 offset 0
```

here i ran these 2 query withing a minute

[image]

and couple of second later

[image]

i keep running the same query and results keeps changing ... not fast every time 
 but every couple of minutes 1 row is added or missing  ! im pretty sure something s wrong with the table or server .... just dont know what and where to look

here is the table structure

[image]

Comment: The order of results can matter when LIMIT is used, and is undefined if not specified by an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Like @Uueerdo said SQL is a unsorted set.. Without using ORDER BY the same order is NOT guaranteed even when running the same query.. This goes for all databases (SQL-Server, SQLite and PostgreSQL to give some examples) that implement SQL as dialect.. To bad this requirement that you need to use ORDER BY with LIMIT to get stabile results is not documented within the MySQL documentation

Comment: @Uueerdo thanx  but its not about the order ... its about rows appearing out of nowhere ... do you think order may effect this behavior ? i mean i have a `limit 20` in there so i thought i have to see at least 20 rows ...  the only way i think to explain this is there are more than 1-2 rows but it doesn't show them for some reason until i delete older ones

Comment: It's not about `ORDER BY` (though such Comments are valid).  Note that the result set has a _different number of rows_.

Comment: Do `SELECT ... WHERE id = 35913` and see if it still matches the `WHERE` clause.  I suspect you will find that something changed in the row.  If so, quietly tuck your tail and delete this Q&A.